# I used feedback from the code review SE for an assignment. Do I have to mark it?

Tags: citations, homework

I wrote source code for an assignment. After I was done and the program was functional, i uploaded a piece (a class) on the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/199970/dsp-quantizer-class-in-c) and people gave me advice, which I then implemented. Should i credit them, and if so, how?

For pieces of code I took from Stackoverflow, for example, I would write it in a comment next to the code, and include a link.

Should this be done in the same way for improvement suggestions? 
In my concrete example, implemented suggestions were mostly about programming language intricacies and object orientation. Another option would be to inform the professor in advance and/or ask about this being allowed.

EDIT: The assignment ist not about the programming languages or object-oriented design.

Comment: When in doubt, cite.

Comment: @yes, and I think the TA will appreciate your honesty (I certainly woulda when I was a TA).

Comment: @JeffE says who?

Comment: [ISWYDT](https://media.giphy.com/media/5gw0VWGbgNm8w/giphy.gif) @TasosPapastylianou

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you should ask the professor in advance and make sure he/she understands what CodeReview actually is.

More generally, you should know (and the professor should effectively communicate) what the parameters are for seeking help. I have doubts that very many professors would permit it, but some would.

The reason for assignments isn't because the professor needs the result. It is to cause a change in *your brain* that won't happen if you take very many short cuts.

Seeking help from the professor or an assistant is different, since they know the actual purpose of the individual assignment (in your learning) and can give hints that won't impede your learning, but help you deepen it. The contributors to CodeReview don't have the context (or usually the background) to do that properly. So you may be sabotoging your learning in pursuit of a better grade. Long term that's a losing game.

Making it functional first was a good step, but there is a lot to good programming beyond functional.

And if you haven't done so, then yes, mark it and point to the source of help. If there weren't already rules around the behavior there should be no reason to punish you and you might get better advice about seeking help from the prof. In fact, you should make the note pretty visible so it just doesn't get lost. Program comments may not be read without some statement at the top pointing to them.

Comment: I don't see how soliciting help from the Code Review hurt the OPs learning. The OP had working source code, he got ideas for how to improve it, and he implemented the ideas. Thus, he had already performed the work that was required for the course. By sending the code to Code Review and implementing improvements, he learned ways to improve his code.

Comment: I can see that it might interfere with the assessment of his work. If his revised program gets an A, where his original program would have gotten a B, then the professor (and some of the other students) might consider this to be unfair.

Comment: @PeterShor My answer isn't about grading and it isn't about fairness. It is about learning. I hope you aren't suggesting that "getting a program working" is enough. Much of the learning about programming is getting it clean, readable, testable, etc etc etc. Learning doesn't stop the first time a program runs.

Comment: Once your students actually get a program working and write adequate comments for it, do they then sit down and spend hours trying to figure out how to improve it? Or do they just turn it in as is? From your answer, you must have amazing students!

Comment: @PeterShor, It's how I work, actually. Suppose you were teaching poetry. Is the first draft what you expect students to turn in? One way to get students to write better programs is to stop reading their work at the first line that you don't understand. Return it to them for improvement. But you also have to have a policy that you are willing to re-grade their work. I've discussed this quite a bit at CSEducators here.

Comment: The assignment is not primarily about programming, I have updated the question.

Comment: @JonasSchwarz, what was it about, then?

Comment: @Buffy: That sounds like a great way to teach advanced programming. So your answer clearly applies to students in your classes, but I suspect it has a fairly limited range of applicability.

Comment: @PeterShor it makes me sad that you are probably correct. But I'm not just talking about "advanced" programming. If bad habits are learned early they become ingrained. As the first hard issue students will fall back on their bad habits. Do it right - from the beginning. Otherwise, why bother?

Comment: @PeterShor It's not your place to decide whether CR has hurt someone's learning. When an instructor gives a grade, they are providing THEIR assessment of the student's learning, and that assessment should be given based on all relevant knowledge. It is not legitimate to withhold information from them based on your personal opinion that they shouldn't be making decisions on it in the first place. If a student disagrees with the instructor's teaching style, they should pursue options other than misrepresentating their work.

Comment: @Accumulation: if you had read my second comment, you would realize that you are completely misinterpreting my views. I was specifically disagreeing with the answer's sentences *"So you may be sabotaging your learning in pursuit of a better grade. Long term that's a losing game."* I totally agree that the student should inform the professor that he obtained help from CR.

Comment: @Accumulation: In my classes, if a student is willing to research a homework problem online, understand the material and use it in a good answer, I am totally in favor. I don't like it if they research a homework problem online, misinterpret the material, and write a totally incorrect solution or a plagiarized solution they don't understand. And I require that they say where they got help. What I was objecting to was the idea "if you use CR, you are sabotaging your professor's carefully thought-out designs to manage your learning experience optimally."

Comment: In the "real world", programmers constantly seek information online and rarely have time to write ideal code. The same elephant is always in the classroom: are you teaching an academic subject or a trade skill? Because the approaches will be *radically* different, to the point where there is almost zero intersection.

Comment: It would be interesting to have a course where assignments were to be done once without outside assistance, and then handed back to be revised with peer review (including other students). It would be interesting to see if the class/groups gravitated to a single solution/style.

Comment: @user3067860, That is pretty much how my courses go. Revision is valued, honored, and supported. However, my courses are (were - I'm retired) in Computer Science, so the quality of programs was important. But poor programs in the sciences and elsewhere produce poor results, so it may not be so different. If you don't have a well-tested, understandable, program you can hardly trust its results.  However, not every program is intended for use by other than its authors. So it is possible to cut some corners, say in the UI. But: tested, and understandable.

Answer (score 4):

Other than taking a few seconds out of your life, the only reason to not mention it is if you think that your instructor would take points off for it. If you're withholding information that you think would affect your grade, that's dishonest. If you disclose it, the worst your instructor can do is mark off points. If you don't, and your instructor finds out about it, they could theoretically accuse you of plagiarism. Citing sources isn't, as many people seem to think, a protection against copyright claims, but it does immunize you against plagiarism claims. If your instructor hasn't given you instructions on citations, you don't need do to anything more than mention that you had your code reviewed on an online forum and that your instructor can ask you for more details if they wish.

Something labeled a take-home "exam" or "test" would be different from something merely labeled an "assignment"; an exam is designed to inform the instructor of your knowledge level, and there is much more of an implied honor system. If there is confusion as to what that honor system consists of, that should be clarified before working on the test. An assignment is an opportunity to practice and to expose to yourself any areas of not understanding before you're actually tested on it. Since the main beneficiary of it is intended to be you, not the instructor, there is less urgency in clarifying the rules prior to working on it.